# Is there a common name for JSON fields in relational tables?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

There is STI-table, which implements the storage of multiple record types. Each type may be accompanied by its own set of additional data. I don't query by these data, so the decision was made to break first normal form and store all the extra data in the JSON format. So... I don't know how to name this column. The first option that comes to my mind is to name the column `extra`, but maybe there are some conventional names?

Update:
I'd like to use `meta`, as json-api does.

Comment: I typically use `attributes`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I forgot to mention that I'm using Rails. So it's a bad idea to use `attributes` as a name for column.

Comment: The joys of obfuscation layers....

Comment: I voted to close this question because it's primarily opinion based. Also there is not one, correct name. It all depends on the situation and for what it's used. `prices`, `attributes`, `categories`, `response`, `properties`, `overlays`, `dynamic_data` could all make sense. Use a name that is recognized and understood in your environment. If everybody knows what `extra` refers to, use it. Otherwise find something different